# Allowing ad-hoc expressions over IEnumerable<MyObj>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, enumerable

I have the following model

```
public class Model
 {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public DateTime HireDate {get;set;}
  public decimal Salary {get;set;}
  public int Hours {get;set;}
 }
```

Now I have the following List

```
List<Model> employees = new List<Model>();
```

I am taking expression string input from user, following are the examples of what user might use

> Salary
>
> Salary + 500
>
> Salary * Hours
>
> SUM(Hours)
>
> SUM(Hours * Salary)
>
> SUM(Hours) / MIN (Hours)

I have to process user's expressions into another IEnumerable of either int or decimal, depending on calculation and which type has higher precision, for example The 3rd Expression will generate the following

```
var result = employees.Select(e => e.Salary * e.Hours)
```

The 4th one will result into this

```
var result = employees.Sum(e => e.Hours)
```

I am currently doing it by first parsing the expression into parse tree and building Expression tree using [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) namespace. With that approach, there is a lot of code and not easily readable by other developers. Is there any easier way ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of doing it again you might find some help on (already pretty old) [Scott Gu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Or at least it should give you a good code base to have a look into

Comment: Is this guy using runtime-compilation ? That creates a dll in-memory everytime an expression is compiled. And my expressions are much simplified than LINQ. Thanks for sharing it though.

Comment: @fahadash He is using the `System.Linq.Expressions` stuff, parsing everything and so on, of cause this has some overhead, by you wrote you do actually the same